# What to add to source list for build dependencies of lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I am having a tough time installing lxml for python 3.6 onto a BeagleBone Black (Debian GNU/Linux version 9).

Based on [this article](https://lxml.de/installation.html), one can run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
```

Then this:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3-lxml
```

However, when I run the 2nd command, I get this error:

```
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

Based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list), I need to modify `sources.list`

**How can I get past this error and install lxml library for Python 3?**

BTW when I run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-lxml
```

It fails with a long message that boils down to

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add something like (you can use a different mirror) `deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main` in your sources.list and then run `apt update` and finally re-run the `apt-get build-dep python3-lxml` command.

Comment: Your proposed comment worked!
I uncommented the second line in my file (`deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free`)
My missing link was `apt update`.  However, fyi needed to use `sudo apt update`
Then I was able to run `sudo apt-get build-dep python3-lxml`